# weird artifacts in the viewport!

Tags: 3d-view, artifacts

im just getting those artifacts in the viewport ,they just showed up .whats the problem here?

[image]

Comment: Probably either an issue with your graphics driver or the GPU.

Comment: it appears only in these project and disappears in sculpt mode

Comment: Given the artifacts I think it's unlikely that it's a bug in Blender but if you want us to check if we can reproduce this, you would have to share your .blend file (https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This case looks a little different but usually when this happens the solution is to go to the Blender viewport's 'View' menu and gradually increase the value of 'Clip Start' until the artefacts disappear.

Also (the following is for beginners who may not yet have noticed the following similar phenomenon), artefacts similar to these will also appear on a specific face (or plane) when 2 (or more) objects are trying to occupy the same plane in space (something obviously impossible in reality). For example, if you select an object and press 'copy' and 'paste', the copy is pasted in exactly the same position as the original, trying to occupy the same space, and these flickering artefacts will then be noticeable if you move your viewing angle.